# Terminator won't launch

Tags: terminal, python3, gnome-terminator

I changed my default python version to python3 on Linux Mint follows:

```
dhruva@DhruvaG2000:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3     10        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3     10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And after this hitting <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> just doesn't do anything, and when I type `terminator` I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 123
    except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
    os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_share_terminator_terminator.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 123
    except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What was the original setting? Was it set to `/usr/bin/python2.7` or to `/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: Originally it was python2.7

Answer (score 1):

Just change it back. Python 2 and 3 are not compatible. By making that change, you have set your default `python` to be `python3` and the system expects `python` to run a python 2 version. The file you have at `/usr/bin/terminator` is a python2 script and you can't run it with python3.

So just run the exact same command and change it back. If you can't open a terminal to run the command, try one of:

1. Open another terminal. Either `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` are likely available on your system.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and in the dialog that appears write `/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/terminator`.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to drop to a tty, log in, and run `sudo update-alternatives --config python` there. You can then come back to the GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or maybe <kbd>F8</kbd>, you might need to try a few F keys).

Comment: Okay I will revert to python2..

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. I'm running Linux Mint 19.3 (same issue with 19.1).
The error is coming from terminator wanting to use Python2.* while /usr/bin/python points to python 3.*

After uninstalling, purging and reinstalling terminator with no luck I found two solutions.

1. Open up /usr/bin/terminator and edit the first line #!/usr/bin/python2
   This will make sure that terminator uses python2 version instead of whatever other python version your using.
2. use update-alternatives to set your default python version to python2

Personally I went for option 1, as that allows me to run my other programs as normal with python 3.